# Count records with a criteria like "within days"

Tags: sql

I have a table as below on sql.

```
OrderID Account  OrderMethod     OrderDate  DispatchDate  DispatchMethod 
2145     qaz     14              20/3/2011  23/3/2011     2
4156     aby     12              15/6/2011  25/6/2011     1
```

I want to count all records that have reordered 'within 30 days' of dispatch date where Dispatch Method is '2' and OrderMethod is '12' and it has come from the same Account.

I want to ask if this all can be achieved with one query or do I need to create different tables and do it in stages as I think I wll have to do now? Please can someone help with a code/query?

Many thanks
T

Comment: How do you determine a reorder? Is this a new record with the same OrderId but different OrderDate?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? Date functions are notoriously different between the different products.

Comment: Sorry. I should have been clearer. If its come from the same Account within 30 days of previous order's dispatch date.

Comment: I am on SQL2005 if that helps

Answer (score 2):

Try the following, replacing [tablename] with the name of your table.

```
SELECT Count(OriginalOrders.OrderID) AS [Total_Orders]
FROM [tablename] AS OriginalOrders  
INNER JOIN [tablename] AS Reorders  
ON OriginalOrders.Account = Reorders.Account  
AND OriginalOrders.OrderDate < Reorders.OrderDate  
AND DATEDIFF(day, OriginalOrders.DispatchDate, Reorders.OrderDate) <= 30  
AND Reorders.DispatchMethod = '2'  
AND Reorders.OrderMethod = '12';
```

By using an inner join you'll be sure to only grab orders that meet all the criteria.
By linking the two tables (which are essentially the same table with itself using aliases) you make sure only orders under the same account are counted.
The results from the join are further filtered based on the criteria you mentioned requiring only orders that have been placed within 30 days of the dispatch date of a previous order.

Answer (score 0):

Totally possible with one query, though my SQL is a little stale..

```
select count(*) from table 
where DispatchMethod = 2
    AND OrderMethod = 12
    AND DATEDIFF(day, OrderDate, DispatchDate) <= 30;
```

(Untested, but it's something similar)

Comment: But I only want to count if its come from the same account. Sorry I didn't mention it in the original post

Answer (score 0):

One query can do it.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)FROM myTable reOrder
INNER JOIN myTable originalOrder
  ON reOrder.Account = originalOrder.Account
  AND reOrder.OrderID <> originalOrder.OrderID
  -- all re-orders that are within 30 days or the 
  -- original orders dispatch date
  AND DATEDIFF(d, originalOrder.DispatchDate, reOrder.OrderDate) <= 30
WHERE reOrder.DispatchMethod = 2
  AND reOrder.OrderMethod = 12
```

Comment: But I only want to count if its come from the same account. Sorry I didn't mention it in the original post.

Comment: I am going to run this and see what it comes up with. Will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

You need a self-join.

The query below assumes that a given account will have either 1 or 2 records in the table - 2 if they've reordered, else 1.

If 3 records exist for a given account, 2 orders + 1 reorder then this won't work - but we'd then need more information on how to distinguish between an order and a reorder.

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable new, myTable prev
 WHERE new.DispatchMethod = 2
 AND new.OrderMethod = 12
 AND DATEDIFF(day, prev.DispatchDate, new.OrderDate)  <=30
 AND prev.Account == new.Account 
 AND prev.OrderDate < new.OrderDate
```

Comment: Does it mean I have to create two tables 'Orders new' and 'Orders prev'?

Comment: No - you just use aliases - copy the above query replacing Orders with the name of your table in BOTH places.

Comment: Renamed to myTable as you put in Q.

Answer (score 0):

Can we use `GROUP BY` in this case, such as the following?

```
SELECT COUNT(Account) 
FROM myTable
WHERE DispatchMethod = 2 AND OrderMethod = 12 
AND DATEDIFF(d, DispatchDate, OrderDate)  <=30
GROUP BY Account
```

Will the above work or am I missing something here?